# Populating a field with firestore data in vue

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I am building a simple vue app where I am registering/logging in users where they are redirected to their own "special" page. I have created a collection (using firestore) called profiles where I am successfully saving all the custom data in a structure like:

```
profiles =>
    ABCDEF1234 (user.uid) =>
        role =>
            customrole: true
        bio: "Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros."
        etc: "etc"    
        etc: "etc"    
        etc: "etc"
```

I have an input in my view where I was trying to pass the bio to, so they can edit their bio, but for the life of me I can not get it to fetch the data.

```
  <input
    type="text"
    name="bio"
    placeholder="bio"
    v-model="info.bio"
  />
```

I could be completely off in how you are supposed to do this, but this is what I currently have. In my data() I currently have:

```
    data() {
        return {
            user: null,

            info: {
                bio:null,
            }
        };
    },
```

I then have in created() (might not be the correct spot for this)

```
const test = firebase.auth().currentUser
  return {
   info: firebase.firestore().collection('profiles').doc(test.uid)
  }
```

I guess I have wrongly assumed that this would "associate" the collection profiles with the current logged in user to info, and then would be used in my data above for me to call like {{info.bio}}. I am still very new to vue, and any helpful guidance or constructive criticism would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: whenever you are referring a variable, you should use `this`. Try using `this.info=value_from_Firebase`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't show a lot of details about your overall Vue.js app architecture, I make the assumption that `firebase.auth().currentUser` returns the current user (i.e. the user is logged in).

Therefore, the following should do the trick:

```
  mounted: function() {
    const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    if (user) {
      firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection("profiles")
        .doc(user.uid)
        .get()
        .then(doc => {
          if (doc.exists) {
            this.info.bio = doc.data().bio;
          } else {
            // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
            console.log("No such document!");
          }
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log("Error getting document:", error);
        });
    }
  }
```

---

Fetching a document from Firestore is an asynchronous operation that returns a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). You therefore need to use the [`then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) method, as explained in the Firestore [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document), in order to wait for the Promise to resolve before being able to assign the value of `bio` to your corresponding Vue.js data property.

Comment: Thanks! That did produce the desired result. Due to it being async, is it normal for it to sometimes take 5 minutes to assign? I do have a lot of CORS errors with localhost with socketjs-node (though I am using the network url)

Comment: No it’s not normal. Fetching one Firestore document is a matter of some fractions of seconds normally. Difficult to give you a more detailed answer without the full view. You may ask a new question with all the details.